Ansible dynamically include vars and roles based on groups
So have an ansible role - lets call it "deploy_app". It is pretty generic for our microservice architecture- we use the same role to deploy all the apps.
We auto-generate an inventory that looks like this
[app1]
hosta
hostb

[app1:vars]
install_dir="/opt/app1"


[app2]
hostc
hostd

[app2:vars]
install_dir="/opt/app2"

Then in our playbook we just do
roles:
 - deploy_app

Works great. Now for my problem- I am trying to figure out a pattern to let me install two apps on the same host.
[app1]
hosta

[app1:vars]
install_dir="/opt/app1"

[app2]
hosta

[app2:vars]
install_dir="/opt/app2"

This inventory file results in only app2 getting installed. I was thinking of trying to parse the group_names to re-include the role...but realised that the value of install_dir for group app1 seems to be completely lost. Any pattern that works here other than adding one play per app - would rather not have to do each app sequentially.

This is a neat solution- two questions- 1. Will ansible be confused and try to run against the same host in separate threads (so have to worry about race conditions) and 2. Am guessing other roles that are supposed to be one per host will be duplicated?


Ansible will treat them as two different hosts (by design, not being confused) so by default it will run the plays in parallel against them. If you don't want this, you can play with throttle and/or serial values. 2. I think that depends on your design. Generally - yes, but maybe it won't be a problem if all the tasks inside are idempotent. Anyway, this is avoidable at a relatively small cost - for example, you can track the list of unique hosts getting involved in a play in pre_tasks, and include the role conditionally when the current one is not on that list yet.


Remove the installation dirs from the inventory and put them into a dictionary. For example, into the groups_vars
shell> cat group_vars/all/install_dir.yml 
install_dir_all:
  app1: /opt/app1
  app2: /opt/app2

install_dirs: "{{ group_names | map('extract', install_dir_all) }}"

Then, the play
- hosts: all

  tasks:

    - debug:
        var: install_dirs

gives for the first inventory
ok: [hosta] => 
  install_dirs:
  - /opt/app1
ok: [hostb] => 
  install_dirs:
  - /opt/app1
ok: [hostc] => 
  install_dirs:
  - /opt/app2
ok: [hostd] => 
  install_dirs:
  - /opt/app2

and for the second one
ok: [hosta] => 
  install_dirs:
  - /opt/app1
  - /opt/app2

Given the simple role for testing
shell> cat roles/deploy_app/tasks/main.yml 
- debug:
    msg: "Install app into the dir: {{ install_dir }}"

Include the role in a loop
- hosts: all

  tasks:

    - include_role:
        name: deploy_app
      loop: "{{ install_dirs }}"
      loop_control:
        loop_var: install_dir

gives (abridged) for the second inventory
ok: [hosta] => 
  msg: 'Install app into the dir: /opt/app1'

ok: [hosta] => 
  msg: 'Install app into the dir: /opt/app2'


In Ansible, the variables are flattened to the host level in runtime, so if a host is a member of several groups, only the latest loaded variable value will survive.
From Assigning a variable to many machines: group variables:

Group variables are a convenient way to apply variables to multiple hosts at once. Before executing, however, Ansible always flattens variables, including inventory variables, to the host level. If a host is a member of multiple groups, Ansible reads variable values from all of those groups. If you assign different values to the same variable in different groups, Ansible chooses which value to use based on internal rules for merging.

But you can actually define different aliases for the same host - the alias will be the inventory_hostname that the variables are mapped to, and the actual hostname/address could be defined explicitly via ansible_host:
; inventory.ini
[app1]
app1host ansible_host=hosta

[app1:vars]
install_dir="/opt/app1"

[app2]
app2host ansible_host=hosta

[app2:vars]
install_dir="/opt/app2"

No changes required for your roles or playbooks. The following example is just to provide an MRE:
# roles/deploy_app/tasks/main.yml
---
- name: Show me the path
  debug:
    var: install_dir

# playbook.yml
---
- name: Install the apps
  hosts: all
  gather_facts: false
  connection: local
  roles:
    - deploy_app

This would result in the following:
PLAY [Install the apps] *********

TASK [deploy_app: Show me the path] ****

ok: [app1host] =>
    install_dir:/opt/app1
ok: [app2host] =>
    install_dir:/opt/app2

PLAY RECAP **

app1host: ok=1 changed=0 unreachable=0 failed=0 skipped=0 rescued=0 ignored=0
app2host: ok=1 changed=0 unreachable=0 failed=0 skipped=0 rescued=0 ignored=0

